# Issue in receiving parameter from controller functions to a view page

Tags: scala, view, playframework-2.1, controllers

I am getting error while trying to receive values in view from controller. In controllers I am using two functions. Both functions return a value to view page

Here is the example:

```
public static Result home() {

    Identity user = (Identity) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
String userEmail = user.email().isDefined() ? user.email().get() : "Not available";
System.out.println("Logged in - "+  userEmail);
String emailCheck = userEmail.substring(userEmail.indexOf("@") + 1, userEmail.length());
emailCheck = emailCheck.substring(0, emailCheck.indexOf("."));

    if (emailCheck.matches(Messages.get("emailCheckAll"))) {
        return ok(home.render(user));
    }

    public static Result getId() {
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        String EAN_code= parameters.get("truckid")[0].trim();
        List<Truck> isvalid= Truck.findTruckId(EAN_code);
        System.out.println(EAN_code);
        System.out.println(isvalid.get(0));
        BigInteger qty=Truck.getTruckQuantity(EAN_code);
        return ok(home.render(qty.toString()));
    }
```

In home.scala.html i am trying to receive like

```
@(user : securesocial.core.Identity)
(qty:String)
@import securesocial.core.IdentityProvider 
@import Http.Context.Implicit
```

but I can't get value from the qty. But I have the value in the controllers. The same value not go to view. Please anyone help me. It shows me error in scala file "value qty not found"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your view as having two parameter lists:

`@(user : securesocial.core.Identity)
(qty:String)`

You're only satisfying one of them when you call the view.

`ok(home.render(qty.toString()))`

Try:

`ok(home.render(user)(qty.toString()))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply dude. But i want to pass parameter from separate function to a single page. Is this possible?. If a particular function gets called it should take that parameter. Can you please help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for but right now you have defined your view to take two lists of parameters and are only supplying one.

Comment: Okay dude. I will explain you clearly.I want to pass parameters from two different function namely getId(),home() to a single view page namely home.scala.html.Because my application should be in a single page. So i should pass variables from different function to achieve different task in same page. In this case what i have to do to resolve my problem Is there any way available ???? Please reply

Comment: I got answer. I decide to catch variable through ajax. thanks for reply